# See the stack of a process or what files and assemblies is calling or using

Tags: windows

Al right! This might sound crazy.

I want to know if it is possible to see the code or something that a specific process is using. I have a scheduled task that is supposed to be ran by a process. The font end to this app says that the scheduled task executed successfully, but I don't see anything in the logs.

I want to know if there is a tool to see what a process is doing.

Comment: How about some context? OS? Platform? Language?

Comment: I'm using a timer job in SharePoint. This is in Win 2003 64 bit and the .Net framework.

Answer (score 1):

The best suite is **Windows Sysinternals** by Mark Russinovich (now bought by Microsoft).
Get it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx).

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

> Ever wondered which program has a
>   particular file or directory open? Now
>   you can find out. Process Explorer
>   shows you information about which
>   handles and DLLs processes have opened
>   or loaded.
>
> The Process Explorer display consists
>   of two sub-windows. The top window
>   always shows a list of the currently
>   active processes, including the names
>   of their owning accounts, whereas the
>   information displayed in the bottom
>   window depends on the mode that
>   Process Explorer is in: if it is in
>   handle mode you'll see the handles
>   that the process selected in the top
>   window has opened; if Process Explorer
>   is in DLL mode you'll see the DLLs and
>   memory-mapped files that the process
>   has loaded. Process Explorer also has
>   a powerful search capability that will
>   quickly show you which processes have
>   particular handles opened or DLLs
>   loaded.
>
> The unique capabilities of Process
>   Explorer make it useful for tracking
>   down DLL-version problems or handle
>   leaks, and provide insight into the
>   way Windows and applications work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which technology you are using, but you could try to remotely debug the application the application, for example using Visual Studio. But to be able to do this you'll need the correct debug information files (.pdb).

If this is your own application you are trying to monitor, inserting some extra logging of some sort will be the easiest solution.

Another option you have is to make a memory dump at the moment you think the application is running. A memory dump is basically a snapshot of the entire memory. YOu can then use a tool like WinDbg to examine the contents of the dump.

Maybe you can give us a little bit more information?

Comment: I'm actually creating a timer job in Sharepoint. It is executed by a windows service called "Windows Sharepoint Services Timer". The web front end for jobs says that the job executed successfully. However, I don't get any log entries. Logs are handled by SharePoint also. This is in WIN 2003 64 bit. Using .Net framework